# url query xml and xpath transform

Tags: xslt, xpath, url-encoding, urldecode

Short question: How to deal with a raw ampersand in xml input file.

ADDED:  Im not even selecting the field with the ampersand. The parser complains at the presence of the ampersand within the file.

Long explanation:
im dealing with xml that is generated via a url response.

```
<NOTE>I%20hope%20this%20won%27t%20require%20a%20signature%3f%20%20
There%20should%20be%20painters%20%26%20stone%20guys%20at%20the
%20house%20on%20Wednesday%2c%20but%20depending%20on%20what%20time%20
it%20is%20delivered%2c%20I%20can%27t%20guarantee%21%20%20
Also%2c%20just%20want%20to%20make%20sure%20the%20billing%20address
%20is%20different%20from%20shipping%20address%3f
</NOTE>
```

which is url decoded into this:

```
<NOTE>I hope this won't require a signature?  
There should be painters & stone guys at the 
house on Wednesday, but depending on what time it is delivered, I can't guarantee!  
Also, just want to make sure the billing address is different from shipping address?  
</NOTE>
```

The Problem:
xslproc chokes on that last string because of the '&' in "painters & stone guys"
with the following error:

```
xmlParseEntityRef: no name
<NOTE>I hope this won't require a signature?  There should be painters &
```

It looks like xsltproc expects a closing `</NOTE>`

Ive tried all manner of `disable-output-escaping="yes"` in various locations. `xsl:output` and `xsl:value-of`

And also tried `xsltproc --decode-uri` but cant figure out that one out. No documentation.

Note:
I wonder if its worth keeping the input in urlencoded format. And using a DOCTYPE..such as the following (not sure how to do that). The output is eventually a browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet  [
    <!ENTITY nbsp   "&#160;">
    <!ENTITY copy   "&#169;">
    <!ENTITY reg    "&#174;">
]>
```

Comment: and also tried encoding="UTF-8" and encoding="ISO-8859-1". Any other valid strings?

Answer (score 0):

The XML is malformed if there's an ampersand that's not escaped. If you put the string inside `<![CDATA[]]>`, then it should work.

```
<NOTE><![CDATA[I hope this won't require a signature?  
  There should be painters & stone guys at the 
  house on Wednesday, but depending on what time it is delivered, I can't guarantee!  
  Also, just want to make sure the billing address is different from shipping address?]]>  
</NOTE>
```

Or, of course, use `&amp;` instead of `&`.

**Edit:** You can also translate the URL escapes into numeric character references if the XSLT processor supports disable-output-escaping (and xsltproc does):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="NOTE">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:call-template name="decodeURL"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="decodeURL">
    <xsl:param name="URL" select="string()"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($URL,'%')">
        <xsl:variable name="remainingURL" select="substring-after($URL,'%')"/>
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="concat(
          substring-before($URL,'%'),
          '&amp;#x',
          substring($remainingURL,1,2),
          ';')"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="decodeURL">
          <xsl:with-param name="URL" select="substring($remainingURL,3)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$URL"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course you don't have to use this transformation as a preprocessing step, you can re-use `decodeURL` in a stylesheet that transforms your source XML that includes the URL encoded string to HTML or whatever.

Comment: that's what im trying to do. the input is %26.

Comment: and the offensive string is 3rd party. so either parse it with xsl or ... a maybe sed, awk or perl.

Comment: Superb. You deserve Gin, Bacon or Cigarettes. Im gathering that if one wants to 'scrub' the input then you pass all nodes via `"@*|node()"`